# using php and java script in a form

Tags: php, button, dhtml, javascript

I am a little bit lost. What I want to achieve is:

- my own custom button
- change onMouseOver etc'
- keep it's size
- post the information to a php server side code

**What I'm missing is:**

- The post - I couldn't figure out how to combine js & php
- The Button size - my code sets a size for the original button but after the rollover it changes

**The code:**

```
<html>  
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        function form_on_click(frm) 
        {
            document.buttonMore.src='bottom_more_click.JPG';
            frm.submit();
        }
    </script> 

    <div style="position: absolute; left: 120px; top: 90px; background-image: url(myBackgroundPicture.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 800px; height: 280px; padding: 15px;">

        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">            
            <input type="text" name="whatever" size= "55" height="100" lang="en" dir="ltr"  style="margin-top: 188px; margin-left: 95px; height: 20px; background-color: transparent; border:none;
            color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: none; font-size: 18px;">

            <a onmouseover="document.buttonMore.src='bottom_more_hover.JPG'"
            onmouseout="document.buttonMore.src='bottom_more_reg.JPG'" 
            onmousedown= "form_on_click(this.form) this.form.submit()"
            onmouseup="document.buttonMore.src='bottom_more_hover.JPG'">

            <img src="bottom_more_reg.jpg" name="buttonMore" height="30" width="173" border="0" alt="MORE!" style="margin-bottom:-10px; margin-left: 15px; height: 30px; width: 100px;">


            </a>
        </form>


    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Oh sure.. excuse me. You're totally right. I don't know where do I have my head.

Try something else, remove this line again

```
onmousedown= "form_on_click(this.form) this.form.submit()"
```

And replace it by

```
href="javascript:form_on_click(this.form);"
```

Just a suggestion, why don't you use an...

```
<input type="button" />
```

...and then customize it in CSS?

**EDIT**

About the size of the button, are those jpeg files equally sized?

Comment: what do you mean? 

If it's not the default submit button, it is mine, the the click does nothing. even if I make the remark as you did...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use JQuery. All of what you want to do can be done with just a few simple steps in JQuery. The mouseover/out submit all of it and tons more.

I fell in love with JQuery...